# Python Numpy Does Not Give Correct Numerical Answer?

Tags: python, numpy, numbers

I wish to compute the following quantity:

[image]

Where:

```
t=14.4022468115
a=2255.5422194535317
b=8.75408541256545
m=2.853672849711247
s=0.4316116619435228
```

My pocket calculator, desmos, and another calculator all agree on the answer `140.636091727`. However, when I try to do this in Python with Numpy:

```
def func(t, a, b, m, s): 
    return b + a*(np.exp((-1)*((np.log(t)-m)**2)/(2*s**2))) / (t)*(s)*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
```

`func(t,a,b,m,s)` gives an answer `163.1201224885765`, which is simply not correct.

What had gone wrong? I searched other posts. Some posts says `np.exp` may not give the right answer in case of overflow or in `float64`. But the result seems to be the same even if I manually round these numbers. Or can it be a syntax error? I have stared at it for too long to notice.

Comment: This gives me your answer: `def func(t, a, b, m, s): 
    return b + a * (1/(s * t * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * (np.exp(- (np.log(t)- m)**2 / (2 * s**2)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the denominator of the fraction in the second section in parentheses:

(t)*(s)*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)  -> ( (t)*(s)*np.sqrt(2*np.pi) )

```
import numpy as np
def func(t, a, b, m, s): 
    return b + a*(np.exp((-1)*((np.log(t)-m)**2)/(2*s**2))) / ((t)*(s)*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))

t=14.4022468115
a=2255.5422194535317
b=8.75408541256545
m=2.853672849711247
s=0.4316116619435228

print(func(t,a,b,m,s)) #140.63609172707763
```

Comment: Lesson learnt. Thank you!

Comment: you welcome, If you don't mind, put my answer as acceptable. best wishes.

Comment: I could not accept answers that was only posted in less than two minutes. But here you go.